# SQL Select Count in Where Clause Performance issue

Tags: sql, performance

I have the following SQL query that performs horribly due to the select count(1) statement in the where clause.  Can anyone suggest a way that would speed this up?  The idea is that I only want rows returned where there is one invoice found.

```
SELECT people.name, people.address 
FROM people 
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM invoices WHERE invoices.pid = people.id)=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [COUNT(1) is superstition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649)
- What you have is a count per row of people = a cursor/loop like action

So, try a JOIN like this

```
SELECT people.name, people.address 
FROM
   people 
   JOIN
   invoices ON invoices.pid = people.id
GROUP BY
   people.name, people.address 
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = 1
```

I'd also hope you have indexes, at least on invoices.pid and people.pid, name, address

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Never heard the voodoo of Count(1). I wonder if that was created by some SEO guy...

Comment: Thanks! Really Box 9 had the answer below too but your explanation of the "superstition" and the additional info helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT people.name, people.address
FROM people
JOIN invoices ON invoices.pid = people.id
GROUP BY people.name, people.address
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining the tables is probably going to be much better in practice and in performance, I should think.

```
SELECT people.name, people.address 
FROM people INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.pid = people.id
```

Edit due to OP being edited: do you want only those people who have exactly one invoice? If so then disregard this and look at one of the other answers.